# Stuck greyed out audits and non-upvotable comments bugs in review queues

Tags: bug, status-review, review-queues, review-audits, comment-votes

When reviewing, I found 2 bugs that seem to appear today.

1. If the next task that you should do is an audit, the post will remain greyed out:

   [image]
2. Sometimes, I'm no longer able to upvote a comment; when I click on the icon, I'm teleported to the top of the page. Sadly, I can't show screen or even have 100% rate. I've got it on reopen votes queue.

Thanks to @A.R.M, here is an example of this bug:
[image: example of bug]

Note: I'm on Google Chrome (version 123.0.6312.59), without any user script, only with uBlock Origin extension enabled.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Are you using any userscripts?

Comment: @Zoeisonstrike I just added a quick explaination about this. No, I'm not. Could it be because of proxy/firewall in my side?

Comment: I just ran into it in suggested edits. It doesn't look like it's directly related to skip. It triggered for me on an audit, and nowhere else. You probably skipped to an audit faster for internal algorithm reasons none of us understand (and that don't matter anyway)

Comment: I'm seeing this too, as well as [some other weird behaviour](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/429600/354577). And I just noticed that commenting in the First Answers queue now automatically advances to the next item. I don't see an announcement about that so not sure if it's deliberate, but I think it's fair to say that comments in review queues are buggy today.

Comment: I noticed the second bug too. Using Waterfox G6.0.11 (64-bit) with no extensions on Fedora KDE: [A GIF displaying the comment upvoting bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPdO8.gif). I had to crop a lot of it to get around the 2 MB size limit.

Comment: @Zoeisonstrike I can confirm it's for audit. I just got it again on first answers, but it were on audit. That's make them easier to see... And thanks A.R.M for the gif, I added it into the post

Comment: I noticed this yesterday, but was hoping nobody would report it since it makes the already broken audit system easier to contend with. Thanks a lot, @Elikill58, for ruining it for the rest of us⸮ :)

Comment: Finally, @Zoeisonstrike, I should note: I was experiencing this issue on a Safari on an iPad, so not likely related to any userscripts, plugins, or even Chrome specifically. These definitely seem like bugs accidentally introduced by some code change on SO's side.

Comment: I noted that sometimes, when I see a post grayed out like that, it is always an audit.

Comment: Looks like #2 is also reported on MSE: [Upvoting comments from review queues often fails because t.state is null](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/398722/1099857)

Comment: Workaround: do a refresh on the page if this occurs and the operation will work again.

Comment: I assume it's reproducible enough but just in case: stacktrace for grayed out audit is `review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=d8246fd945d5:1 Uncaught TypeError: e.comments.extendCommentUi is not a function
    at q (review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=d8246fd945d5:1:28197)
    at L (review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=d8246fd945d5:1:32123)
    at C (review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=d8246fd945d5:1:18258)
    at Object.success (review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=d8246fd945d5:1:23523)
    at fire (jquery.js:3232:31)`... guessing something comment-related throws and then the review never gets un-grayed