# "False audits" in the review queues?

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits

**TL;DR:** Some non-audit reviews are displaying "This is an audit" when I try to add a comment.

Twice recently I've tried to add a comment on a post in the review queues and seen the familiar "This is an audit" popup that happens when commenting on an audit. I then finished my review, but instead of being greeted with the standard "Congratulations!" message associated with audits I got the next item in the queue, as if it were a regular review.

Going back to the review page, audits show something like "Audit passed". In this case it just shows the action I took. Visiting the post in a separate tab doesn't show any obvious signs that the post had been selected as an audit. It's not deleted, the score and user are unchanged from what I saw in review, etc.

I lost track of the first post where this occurred, but I *think* both had recently been edited by a moderator. The edits don't seem to indicate anything special. I also think they were both in the reopen queue. [Here's the most recent one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/35837437).

Is this a bug?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/35837437) does not appear to be an audit.  An audit would not show multiple user's votes.  It would only show your own vote; at least, that's the case in my experience. The [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78224713/timeline) for the question seems to suggest it was an actual review item, not an audit.

Comment: @SecurityHound, that's more or less the point. The "This is an audit" comment popup is being triggered on non-audits. I'll rephrase to clarify.

Comment: Maybe its an audit of audits.

Comment: It's audits all the way down

Comment: FWIW: I noticed this exact behavior in the _Low Quality Answers_ queue, but not in the _First Answers_ queue—even though [the other bugs that @Elikill58 reported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429598/stuck-greyed-out-posts-and-non-upvotable-comments-bugs-in-review-queues) appear in both.