# All audits grayed out - by design or bug?

Tags: bug, review-audits

I can see similar questions about "grayed out" stuff in review queue, but I think this specific issue have not been raised. Also, I am not sure if this is by design — maybe it's supposed to be that way? But other questions about audits make me think that they are supposed to look like normal reviews.

Issue:
So far, every audit I got was permanently grayed out. I could still take action, which resulted in "Congratulations! [...] you passed" message. But I thought I was not supposed to know when something is an audit, and so far, it being grayed indicated audits 100% of the time for me.

Refreshing the page has it still gray.

It seems to happen with every audit, regardless of how fast I went there, unlike [this suggested duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429598/stuck-greyed-out-posts-and-non-upvotable-comments-bugs-in-review-queues).

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/35853343

Here it is grayed out: [image: pic]

And sure enough, it's an audit:

[image: pic]

Stack trace in the console:

```
review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=d8246fd945d5:1 Uncaught TypeError: e.comments.extendCommentUi is not a function
    at q (review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=d8246fd945d5:1:28197)
    at L (review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=d8246fd945d5:1:32123)
    at C (review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=d8246fd945d5:1:18258)
    at Object.success (review-v2-transpiled.en.js?v=d8246fd945d5:1:23523)
    at fire (jquery.js:3232:31)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3362:7)
    at done (jquery.js:9840:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.js:10311:8)
```

Comment: I've seen this as well, looks like a bug to me.

Comment: This appears to be network-wide: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398809